# AWS Chime useToggleLocalMute() does not working

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, mute, amazon-chime, aws-chime-sdk

Hi guys i'm trying to create a button that disables my microphone in ws-chime, i followed the documentation to the letter only that when i click on the button nothing seems to happen.

```
 const { muted, toggleMute } = useToggleLocalMute();
<button onClick={toggleMute}>
          {muted ? "Unmute myself" : "Mute myself"}
        </button>
```

Comment: I found the same behavior, it seems that the toggleMute is not changing the muted state

Answer (score 0):

I could simulate that problem and searching on the internet I could find [this post on github](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/issues/195) related to this problem.

I tried to implement what was suggested there but didn't work for me, so I decided to work with the `const meetingManager = useMeetingManager();`

By using that, I was able to mute/unmute by calling

```
await meetingManager.audioVideo?.realtimeUnmuteLocalAudio();

await meetingManager.audioVideo?.realtimeMuteLocalAudio();
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but that worked for me until they update their documentation as mentioned in the post on github.